# Run Simulink changing input varaibles from Matlab function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am running Simulink from a Matlab function, as I need to start and stop the simulation multiple times changing parameters. When I run Simulink from the main script, there are no problems, Simulink can read the workspace. However, as soon as I make the script as a function so that I can run it for different input data.

```
function [Out] = Funtion (Var1, Var2 ....)
        simout = sim('Simulinkblock');
        Yx = simout.yout{1}.Values.Data;
        Cx = Yx(end);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulink reads from the base workspace by default, you either need to change this using the following `simset` options in your function:

```
options = simset('SrcWorkspace','current');
sim('modelname',[],options)
```

Or assign the variables to the base workspace from your function using `assignin` before calling `sim`